# Change Alexa tracking inbound links from non-www to www version of site

Tags: traffic, web-traffic, traffic-measurement, alexa-internet

I have problem with Alexa tracking for a website (eg: example.com) that redirects from non-www to www.

For some reason, Alexa displays the inbound links from the non-www version istead of the www version. For the www version I have over 2000 inbound links but on the non-www one I only have 10.

Is there any way I could make Alexa show the correct number of inbound links?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you are using the correct links in your sitemap and especially your dmoz listing.